# ( Performance advantage )2015 Macbook pro 13" 8GB vs 16GB model?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, display, apple-configurator, apple-hardware-test

I m planning to buy Macbook pro 13" 2015 model for day to day development purpose. I m confused b/w 8GB and 16GB version.!! Does 16GB version gives much performance advantage over 8GB version?? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Many thanks in advance. Here are the complete specs:

Specifications:
2.7GHz Dual-core Intel Core i5, Turbo Boost up to 3.1GHz
16GB or 8GB 1866MHz LPDDR3 SDRAM
128GB PCIe-based Flash Storage
Intel Iris Graphics 6100
Force Touch trackpad
Accessory Kit
Backlit Keyboard (English) & User's Guide

Comment: What kind of development?

Comment: Majorly Android development using virtual devices. Also I may run virtual machines.

Comment: The only difference between these models is RAM.  Virtualization needs RAM, so the more the better but, still it depends largely on what kind of VM you are running.  Linux? Windows? Both?  Please update your question with more information.  How do you do your Android dev now?

Comment: Using android studio on windows machine

Comment: You definitely want 16GB for that. Android Studio and the Android emulator (with or without HAXM) like having a lot of memory.  With the android emulator, you're running a full system image of a phone.  (Compared to the iOS emulator, which thunks down to OS frameworks for a lot of things.)  Imagine running the rest of your Mac with 4-6GB of memory and that's what you'll be at with 8GB.

Comment: I'm going to close this as hardware shopping / off topic. Aside from being primarily opinion based, you'll want to either ask how to benchmark your current computer to determine the RAM needs of your next purchase or explain exactly the workload you need to perform. Many people use the 2015 MacBook for day to day development, so it's hard to justify the added expense of your two Macs without some hard and fast requirements. (1.1GHz dual-core Intel Core M processor with 8 GB of RAM)

Answer (score 2):

See this tread on [Apple Support Forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5475807)

Poster OGELTHORPE writes:

> With an SSD, RAM is not as critical.  **If the bank account permits,
>   then purchase the 16 GB**, if not I think you will find the 8 GB will
>   not be that much of a handicap  Look at [this diagram](https://discussions.apple.com/servlet/JiveServlet/showImage/2-23495408-315665/Screen+Shot+2013-08-15+at+4.50.27+PM.png) of the affect of
>   RAM and SSD.  Note that the increase to 16 GB from 8 GB is very
>   marginal.

Comment: -1 Photoshop needing RAM isn't necessarily a good proxy for "development" IMO. I'm not actually -1 you since the problem is with the question being imprecise and you are just trying to guess what the OP actually needs.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to guess his needs. The OP was very vague.

Answer (score 1):

For development especially if you use VM's then 16GB is better since you can "simulate" in this way a more powerful machine. Its only a matter of money of course but if you can, do it! 
(especially since you can't upgrade at a later time)

I use a 16GB Macbook pro myself and I am able to run Linux/Win VMs for development and it is really great that my machine doesn't feel sluggish at all.
(On the contrary! My best Windows experience is running as a VM on my Macbook pro with 8GB available and then having 8 GB for all native mac work. The same goes with Linux based VMs)

Comment: +1 for VM as a real reason to get more than 8 GB of RAM. I also run VM on the MacBook (1.1 GHz core duo) and get real work done. My VM are all unix, though. I'd be wanting 16 GB if I ran Windows unless I could be sure things would be copacetic in 8.